# E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677): Failed to close existing event stream

Tags: java, flutter

I have started development in flutter. In one scenario I have to check if the user is connected to internet or not. I am using [connectivity 0.4.9+5](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) and [data_connection_checker 0.3.4](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker) in combination to check if user has active connection or not.

I have create one file internet_connectivity_service.dart which perform all the task related to it.

```
class InternetConnectivityService {
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _subscription;

  /*
    * This function check if the device has internet connectivity.
    * With the help of DataConnectionChecker it checks for actual internet connectivity. 
  */
  Future<bool> _checkConnectivity() async {
    if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /*
    * This function is invoked to on each connection change request.
    * Using Connectivity package it will check for connectivity and connection type.
    * This function has return type of Future<bool> which perform async request to check connectivity.
    * After checking connection type it check for divice has internet accesssible or not.
  */
  Future<bool> _hasInternet() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      return _checkConnectivity();
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      return _checkConnectivity();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> initInterNetConnectivitySubscription(
      BuildContext context) {
    // * Subscribe to connectivity changes
    _subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen(
      (ConnectivityResult result) {
        _hasInternet().then(
          (result) {
            // * When internet is disconnected
            Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
            if (!result) {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                snackBarBuilder(
                    color: kErrorColor,
                    text: 'Connection Lost',
                    context: context),
              );
            } else {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                snackBarBuilder(
                    color: kSuccessColor, text: 'Connected', context: context),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
    return _subscription;
  }

  disposeSubscription() {
    _subscription.cancel();
  }
}
```

Function `initInterNetConnectivitySubscription` and `disposeSubscription` are used for subscribe and unsubscribe for particular event. I am calling these methods from component where I want this functionality.

For Example:

```
     InternetConnectivityService internetConnectivityService =
      InternetConnectivityService();

  @override
  initState() {
    internetConnectivityService.initInterNetConnectivitySubscription(context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    internetConnectivityService.disposeSubscription();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

By doing so functionality is working sometimes but sometimes I am facing error stating  `E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677): Failed to close existing event stream`.

Complete stack trace.

```
   Restarted application in 5,259ms.
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677): Failed to close existing event stream
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NetworkCallback was not registered
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:50)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at android.net.ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4009)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at io.flutter.plugins.connectivity.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.onCancel(ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:53)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onListen(EventChannel.java:182)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onMessage(EventChannel.java:167)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/EventChannel#plugins.flutter.io/connectivity_status(28677):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)**strong text**
```

Due to this error my application is not getting crash but sometime functionality doesnot work as desired. Please let me know if I am making some mistake or if their is better way of doing so. I just wan't to have functionality in which when user don't have connection than application will show stating that you are not connected to internet.

Comment: I'm receiving the same error here, but only by using the connectivity package. Every time I hot-restart the app this error pops up and messes things up. Getting really tired of the way Flutter team develops their official plugins. It's pure lack of respect towards us.

Comment: I have the same problem, if someone has a solution it would be good to share it.

Comment: same here. provider stops functioning properly.

Comment: Same problem here. Any updates on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have already solved this problem so this if for the people who come in the future and still have this problem.

I fixed it by upgrading to the latest version where they fixed the issue:

```yaml
connectivity: ^2.0.2
```